# Is everyone in the justice department a Judge

Tags: dredd, 2000ad

When reading up on the lore every character in the Justice Department is called a judge. I wonder is that for all members of the justice department or is that just for specific positions of authority

Comment: http://judgedredd.wikia.com/wiki/Judge_Classes

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell all Justice Department characters in the stories are Judges. However, some will be cadets (who are not full Judges) and there may well be staff like medical staff or cleaners etc. who are not Judges, but are not mentioned.

See the Wikipedia page on the [minor characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_characters_in_Judge_Dredd) for a list of minor characters, all of which are Judges.

Also there is a discussion on the [2000ad Forum](https://forums.2000ad.com/index.php?topic=44222.0) about this which has an organization chart that shows Civilian Med Services (Bottom left) in the answer by Joe Soap, which implies there may be civilian medical staff, but that's about it. All the rest seem to be Judges of one sort or another.

Comment: It's been mentioned that everyone in the equivalent departments in most of the mega-cities is a Judge, even the accountants. Brit-Cit is the major exception as they have Administrators to do that sort of work.

Comment: Honestly making everyone even the guy that replaces the lightbulbs a judge makes the title feel rather worthless, but that is a matter to be debted someplace else